# List of available Wifi devices

Tags: android

I want to display list of Available Wifi devices. This is my code, I do not understand what mistake is here:

```
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
   {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
   }   
String[] str1 = null;
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,str1);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
textStatus.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());
 boolean b=wifi.isWifiEnabled();
if(b){
 wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
enter code here
```

---

This is my code, I want to get Wifi enabled device properties specifically in Android by programmatically. How can I get that?

```
 public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
 {
 results = wifi.getScanResults();
 size = results.size();
 int i = 0;
 str1 = new String[size];
 for (ScanResult result : results){
 str1[i] = result.SSID + " " + result.level;
 i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the available WIFI Scan results by

```
List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
```

Then iterating over `mScanResults` and getting SSID using `results.SSID`. Also if you are interested to get the best network you can use `WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(int rssiA, int rssiB)` for comparing two networks.

```
ScanResult bestResult = null;
for(ScanResult results : mScanResults){
   Log.d("result",results.SSID);
   if(bestResult == null || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestResult.level,
                                                         results.level) < 0){
      bestResult = results;
   }
}
String message = String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest.", 
                                           mScanResults.size(), bestResult.SSID);
Log.d("best network",message);
```

You can download complete demo from my [`repository`](https://github.com/lalit3686/WIFIConnectionListener).

Comment: How do i wanna put it in String Array then set adapter using listview?

Comment: Here, how should i use SSID in lists but i have written my code like this,                                                       for (ScanResult result : results){                             str1[i] = result.SSID + " " +result.level;
i++;
}

Comment: List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults(); - and applicatoin close without error:(wifi!=null) How to fix it?

Comment: it doesn't seems to work on Android 11. scan results are empty and require to move to wifi screen and run a scan manually. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;    
import java.util.List;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;    
import android.content.Intent;     
import android.content.IntentFilter;    
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;    
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;   
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.util.Log;   
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
import android.widget.AdapterView;    
import android.widget.Button;    
import android.widget.ListView;    
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;    
import android.widget.TextView;    
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {      
    WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }   
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WiFiDemo.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try 
        {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) 
            {   
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }         
    }    
}
```

Comment: Without using Toast, i need to display all lists of Wifi Devices in Listview by using Array Adapter . How shoud i do that ? I am very new to this Android , i am beginner please can anyone help me here ? And sorry if i am wrong !

Comment: in this example i listout all the available wifi in listview . Please take one textview,button and listview in main.xml file and give it id as per example .

Comment: @ chirag : What we have to do for connect that particular wifi through code?

Answer (score 1):

based on the android developer website the best way to search a list of wifi is as following:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
                   context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                       WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false);
    if (success) {
      scanSuccess();
    } else {
      // scan failure handling
      scanFailure();
    }
  }
};

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter);

boolean success = wifiManager.startScan();
if (!success) {
  // scan failure handling
  scanFailure();
}

....

private void scanSuccess() {
  List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
  ... use new scan results ...
}

private void scanFailure() {
  // handle failure: new scan did NOT succeed
  // consider using old scan results: these are the OLD results!
  List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
  ... potentially use older scan results ...
}
```

> Android 8.0 and Android 8.1:

A successful call to WifiManager.getScanResults() requires any one of the following permissions:

- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

If the calling app does not have any of these permissions, the call fails with a SecurityException.

Alternatively, on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can use the CompanionDeviceManager to perform a scan of nearby companion devices on behalf of your app without requiring location permission.

source : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan